# Access radio inside div based on text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple div with radio button for each , what I am looking for is to get Tilte and click on radio button for each div , .
Here is HTML for that .

```
<div id="iff-campaigns">
    <div id="iff-campaign52249" class="iff-campaign-container iffhidden" onmouseover="IffAdvertismentAction(52249,&quot;over&quot;);" onmouseout="IffAdvertismentAction(52249,&quot;out&quot;);">
        <div class="iff-title">Would you like to get paid to take Surveys and Fun IQ Tests?</div>
        <div class="iff-optin">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52249" id="iffinputyes-52249" value="Yes" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52249,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">Yes</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52249" id="iffinputno-52249" value="No" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52249,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">No</label>
        </div>
        <div id="div-cq52249" class="iff-div-customquestions-survey">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-first5224915243" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> First Name: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="ifffirst~52249~15243" name="ifffirst~52249~15243" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;ifffirst~52249~15243&quot;,&quot;first&quot;,1,1);" regfld=""> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-last5224915244" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Last Name: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="ifflast~52249~15244" name="ifflast~52249~15244" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;ifflast~52249~15244&quot;,&quot;last&quot;,1,1);" regfld=""> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-email5224915245" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Email Address: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="iffemail~52249~15245" name="iffemail~52249~15245" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;iffemail~52249~15245&quot;,&quot;email&quot;,1,1);" regfld="^[^<>s@]+(@[^<>s@]+(.[^<>s@]+)+)$"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="iff-rollup52249" class="iff-roleup"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="iff-campaign52706" class="iff-campaign-container" onmouseover="IffAdvertismentAction(52706,&quot;over&quot;);" onmouseout="IffAdvertismentAction(52706,&quot;out&quot;);">
        <div class="iff-title">Would you like the days important news broken down into a quick and informative read each morning?</div>
        <div class="iff-optin">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52706" id="iffinputyes-52706" value="Yes" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52706,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">Yes</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52706" id="iffinputno-52706" value="No" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52706,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">No</label>
        </div>
        <div id="div-cq52706" class="iff-div-customquestions-survey">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-email5270620435" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Email Address: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="iffemail~52706~20435" name="iffemail~52706~20435" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;iffemail~52706~20435&quot;,&quot;email&quot;,1,1);" regfld="^[^<>s@]+(@[^<>s@]+(.[^<>s@]+)+)$"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="iff-rollup52706" class="iff-roleup"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="iff-campaign52912" class="iff-campaign-container" onmouseover="IffAdvertismentAction(52912,&quot;over&quot;);" onmouseout="IffAdvertismentAction(52912,&quot;out&quot;);">
        <div class="iff-title">Ready to take cooking to the next level? </div>
        <div class="iff-optin">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52912" id="iffinputyes-52912" value="Yes" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52912,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">Yes</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52912" id="iffinputno-52912" value="No" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52912,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">No</label>
        </div>
        <div id="div-cq52912" class="iff-div-customquestions-survey">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-first5291222515" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> First Name: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="ifffirst~52912~22515" name="ifffirst~52912~22515" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;ifffirst~52912~22515&quot;,&quot;first&quot;,1,1);" regfld=""> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-last5291222516" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Last Name: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="ifflast~52912~22516" name="ifflast~52912~22516" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;ifflast~52912~22516&quot;,&quot;last&quot;,1,1);" regfld=""> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-email5291222517" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Email Address: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="iffemail~52912~22517" name="iffemail~52912~22517" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;iffemail~52912~22517&quot;,&quot;email&quot;,1,1);" regfld="^[^<>s@]+(@[^<>s@]+(.[^<>s@]+)+)$"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-zip5291222522" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Zip: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="iffzip~52912~22522" name="iffzip~52912~22522" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;iffzip~52912~22522&quot;,&quot;zip&quot;,1,1);" regfld="(^d{5}$)|(^d{5}-d{4}$)|^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])+{0,1}(d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]d)$"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="iff-rollup52912" class="iff-roleup"> </div>
    </div>
    <div id="iff-campaign52230" class="iff-campaign-container" onmouseover="IffAdvertismentAction(52230,&quot;over&quot;);" onmouseout="IffAdvertismentAction(52230,&quot;out&quot;);">
        <div class="iff-title">Would you like to receive FREE Severe Local Weather Alerts straight to your inbox? These can be life saving! </div>
        <div class="iff-optin">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52230" id="iffinputyes-52230" value="Yes" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52230,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">Yes</label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="iffinput-52230" id="iffinputno-52230" value="No" onclick="IffAdvertismentSelect(52230,false,&quot;&quot;,false);">No</label>
        </div>
        <div id="div-cq52230" class="iff-div-customquestions-survey">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-email5223015020" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Email Address: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="iffemail~52230~15020" name="iffemail~52230~15020" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;iffemail~52230~15020&quot;,&quot;email&quot;,1,1);" regfld="^[^<>s@]+(@[^<>s@]+(.[^<>s@]+)+)$"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div id="div-zip5223015025" class="iff-customquestion">
                <div class="iff-cqlabel"> <span>*&nbsp;</span> Zip: </div>
                <div class="iff-cqcontrol">
                    <input type="text" id="iffzip~52230~15025" name="iffzip~52230~15025" value="" class="iff-input-text" onblur="Ifffieldchange(&quot;iffzip~52230~15025&quot;,&quot;zip&quot;,1,1);" regfld="(^d{5}$)|(^d{5}-d{4}$)|^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])+{0,1}(d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]d)$"> </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="iff-rollup52230" class="iff-roleup"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried following but does not work :

```
//div[contains(text(),'" +textvalue+ "')]/preceding:://input[@value='Yes'])
```

I need to extract Text and click on Radio button for every div .

```
List<WebElement> camp2 = driver.findElements(By.className("iff-title"));
                    System.out.println(camp2.size());
                    for (WebElement title2: camp2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Camp Title - "+title2.getText());
                        String text = title2.getText();
                        if(text.isEmpty())
                        {
                            System.out.println("Null Value found");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WebElement div = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'"+text+"')]"));
                            div.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Yes']")).click();
                            System.out.println("In Else loop.");
                        }
                        //div[contains(text(),'Would you like a Gift Card for a FREE Website, Blog or Online Store?')]
                    }
```

Comment: Can you just explain furthur

Comment: Regarding what ,

Comment: I need to click on radio button , which is present in div , problem is there are multiple div with same id , so what I come up is to lock a div based on text and then move to radio element in that div and click on it.

Comment: You want to click a radio button and on clicking that you want its relevant data?

Comment: Can you once again `System.out.println(camp2.size())` after `List<WebElement> camp2 = driver.findElements(By.className("iff-title"))` It should return 4.

Comment: 1. Would you like to get paid to take Surveys and Fun IQ Tests? 2. Would you like the days important news broken down into a quick and informative read each morning? 3. Ready to take cooking to the next level? 4. Would you like to receive FREE Severe Local Weather Alerts straight to your inbox? These can be life saving!

Comment: Do you always want to Answer `Yes` for all the questions?

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
//for yes radio button
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.iff-optin label:nth-child(1) input")).click();

//for No radio button
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.iff-optin label:nth-child(2) input")).click();
```

**UPDATE:**

if you just want to check yes for all radios, following is the code for you :

```
 List<WebElement> camp2 = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.iff-optin label:nth-child(1) input"));

    System.out.println(camp2.size());

    for(WebElement ele :camp2){
        ele.click();


    }
```

Comment: It click only radio option for first div :

Comment: List<WebElement> camp2 = driver.findElements(By.className("iff-title"));
     for (WebElement title2: camp2)
     {
      System.out.println("Camp Title - "+title2.getText());
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.iff-optin label:nth-child(1) input")).click();
     }

Comment: so what is the result?

Comment: It click on first radio button only , I have multiple div and radio button top it.

Comment: But in your HTML code there are only two radio buttons

Comment: Yes , but Have multiple div of same HTML structure , thats why me using for loop to go in each div and click on radio button inside every div.

Comment: Add this before for loop and share result : `System.out.println(camp2.size());`

Comment: Its five me size of 3 .

Comment: Its give me size of 3 .

Comment: @SujitSoni : I've updated my code; if you just want to click all "Yes" radio buttons.